# Is there a way in Power BI to show the sum of multiple columns randomly

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization

I have three columns value in my Power BI report
let's just name them column1, column2, column3
I'm wondering if there is a visualization in Power BI that can show their sum value randomly
For example, in this visualization, 
I can either select to show the sum value of column1+column2+column3 all toghther
or show two of them like column1 + column3, column2+ column3, and column1+column2 etc.
or just single column's value
I hope there is a selector in the visualization that I can select the columns' value I want to show as sum

Is there a way in Power BI to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `RANDBETWEEN` function to randomly choose whether or not to include a column (0 or 1).

```
Rand = [Column1] * RANDBETWEEN(0,1) +
       [Column2] * RANDBETWEEN(0,1) +
       [Column3] * RANDBETWEEN(0,1)
```

Note that this does have the possibility of summing none of the three.

Comment: Hi Alexis, is there a way to select the columns' sum by me manually, not totally random, e.g. if I want to select column 1 and 2, is it possible to create a filter or selector that I can just select these two columns and show their sum

Comment: Yeah, just replace `RANDBETWEEN` with your selection condition. E.g., you could create a new `Slicer` table with a single column, `ColNum`, and three rows `"Col1","Col2","Col3"`, stick that on a slicer and use `("Col1" IN VALUES(Slicer[ColNum]))` as the first condition. 2nd and 3rd analogously.